# Laravel 4 Cookie Key but no Value

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-4

Hey everyone I am having trouble with cookies in Laravel 4.

I am using a rest client to test an api that I am working on and I wanted to add a layer of authentication that went according to cookies.

In my route, I put in the following code to filter for it:

```
Route::filter('check_cookie', function(){
 var_dump(Cookie::get());
});
```

I see the var dump happening but the weird thing is that I see the cookie Key but not the value. so I see in the dump an array like:

```
array(1) {
 ["api_cookie"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Well where did you set the cookie?

Comment: REST is supposed to be stateless, so you shouldn't be using cookies at all.

Comment: I was using cookies as an authentication layer. Granted it should be stateless but this seemed like a decent and KISS way.

Comment: As for where the cookie was set, I actually was just passing it in the header on a rest api tester. I wanted to see if I can grab a cookie and dump it. I am seeing that when I dump it the value is not there.

Comment: Any resolution for this issue?

Comment: Yep. Use a more recent version of Laravel, cookie support is better. Latest is 5.3 (just out).